# Cannot resolve keyword 'field_object' into field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a field object that I want to do filtering with
Since the filter field will change dynamically.

```
only_user=User.objects.first()

field_object = only_user._meta.get_field(field)
field_object2 = only_user._meta.get_field(field2)    
QuerySet = User.objects.filter(Q(field_object="xxx")|Q(field_object2="yyy"))
```

But I couldn't do it, it said

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'field_object' into field. Choices are: .....
```

EDIT:

I figure it out, Thank You:

```
       sub_filter = {field: field_value}
       sub_filter = {field2: field_value}
        q_list=[Q(**sub_filter),Q(**sub_filter2)]
        QuerySet = User.objects.filter(
            reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass `field_object` directly in filter. Because you can't pass a variable as key of keyword argument.

Try like this:

```
field_object = only_candidate._meta.get_field(field)
query1 = { field_object : 'xxx' }
query2 = { field_object2 : 'yyy' }
QuerySet = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(**query1)|Q(**query2))
```

Basically here I am creating a dictionary using `field_object`, and key is `field_object` and value is the actual value you want to query. Then using `**query` I am converting the dictionary to `key=value` and passing it through filter.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I need to do filtering with OR,
How would I do it with OR on more than one field